# Remove Parsley-Rails error messages, Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parsley.js

I am using fantastic gem "parsley-rails", it works just perfect for my application.

But now I am facing problem of removing those error messages, because they change form layout.

My html looks like this :

```
  <input data-parsley-minlength="3" data-show-errors="false" id="message_name" name="message[name]" placeholder="Kā Jūs sauc ?*" required="required" type="text" data-parsley-id="9402" class="parsley-error"><ul class="parsley-errors-list filled" id="parsley-id-9402"><li class="parsley-required">This value is required.</li></ul>
```

My css:

```
li.parsley-required {
  display:none !important;
}
ul.parsley-errors-list {
  display:none !important;
}
ul.parsley-error-list li {
  display:none !important;
}
```

This code hide all error messages on first validate click. But If I change input value error message is shown again.

I tried to look some Google results, but no valid resources.

Any tip on this ? Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not clear what you're trying to do.

Errors should get removed automatically by `parsley`.

If you're doing something funky, call `$form.parsley().validate()` on your form, or call `$field.parsley().reset()` on .